# How to return a value from lambda function

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have this code and it's work correctly,

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var func = new Action<int, int>((a, b) =>
        {
            var sum = a + b;
            MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
            //How can I return sum?
        });

        //var result=func(2,3);
        func(2, 3);
    }
```

How I can change func to return **sum** variable, I want use function as:

```
   var result=func(2,3);
```

Comment: Can u explain the relation of your subject and your question?!

Comment: Sounds like you want `Func<int, int, int>` which you can return a+b from

Comment: @Charleh sorry for wrong title, if you vote down me please vote me up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Action` represents a method which **does not return a value**.

If you want to return a value you need to use a [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) 
which encapsulates a method that returns a value of the type specified by the `TResult` parameter.

So in your case you need a `Func<T1, T2, TResult>` where the arguments are `int` and so does the return type:

```
var func = new Func<int, int, int>((a, b) =>
{
    var sum = a + b;
    MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
    return sum;
});

var result=func(2,3);
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but you don't need the `new` syntax when you create a delegate from a lambda, so either `Func<int, int, int> func = (a, b) => { var sum = a + b; MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString()); return sum; };` or `var func = (Func<int, int, int>)((a, b) => { var sum = a + b; MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString()); return sum; });` will give the same.